# Fetching all links in a website using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to fetch all the links in  a website and click each one to those. Basically I want to check if that website have any broken links or not?

One way I was thinking is to add all the links in home map with key as its text and keep on adding in map till all the links in menu item pages are added and then iterate on map and click on each link.

But I know this is not the best solution as we can still miss some links.

Does anybody have any other better solution to this?

Comment: You can use Selenium to the website. Find all links. Click it one by one. Try/Catch `TimeoutException` when it clicks.

Comment: To verify the broken links in a page, it doesn't need to click links you fetched. After fetching all links in a webpage -- check the HTTP status code is 200 or not. If it's 200 links are functional and not broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below method to verify links are broken or not.

```
try {
            List<WebElement> anchorTagsList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            System.out.println("Total no. of links are " + anchorTagsList.size());
            for (WebElement anchorTagElement : anchorTagsList) {
                if (anchorTagElement != null) {
                    verifyURLStatus(anchorTagElement.getAttribute("href"));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static List<String> verifyURLStatus(String URL) throws Exception {
        List<String> invalidURL = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(URL);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnect.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            httpURLConnect.connect();
            if (httpURLConnect.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                System.out.println("Valid URL " + URL);
            } else {
                invalidURL.add(URL);
                System.out.println("In Valid URL " + URL);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Failed to validate broken link");
        }
        return invalidURL;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah this one is good if I want to check status of URL but how to fetch all the urls in the website using selenium?

Comment: @NJin , Did it helpful?

Comment: It was helpful to some extent specially code for checking status but I am not able to fetch all the url in the website.

Comment: @NJin , Did you check my updated code? i am able to get all the URLs in the website with the above code.

Comment: Yes I am able to get all the url in teh page given but I want to get all the urls inside each  page but also want unique urls only. I one url exists on one page and same existing on other, I want to keep one copy only.

Comment: Then you have navigate to each page , and to get unique urls you can use set instead of list

Answer (score 0):

Pradeep's answer is good for validating links, but you seem to be asking how to -get- the links in the first place.

```
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
```

If you were to then use Pradeep's method, you'd need to pass the URL's as strings:

```
for(WebElement link : allLinks)
    verifyURLStatus(link.getAttribute("href"));
```

My example ignores the returned list array of invalid URL's, but you get the idea.