# Java - Want to produce a list of returned google search url's and then match them to a different url to find a hit - Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-search

I'm trying to create a program that will search keywords in google and then match the search results with a website url and if the url matches it will save the page and position on page in which that url was found. However, whenever I print the size of the list it returns 0

code:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
        element.sendKeys(keyword);
        element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
        int page = 0;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hitList = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for(int i=page;i<=pageNo;i++) {
            List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.className("_Rm"));
            System.out.println(list.size());
            Thread.sleep(10000);

            for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++) {
                String site = list.get(j).getText();
                if(site.contains(website)) {
                    hitList.put(i, j);
                }

                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pnnext']/span[2]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
```

Comment: This might help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48556267/7877196

Comment: Unable to find any element with class '_Rm'. To  get the links on a page use this css selector - "div[class='g'] h3[class='r'] > a"

Comment: I don't see where pageNo is declared and initialized. Maybe it's initialized to 0?

Comment: PageNo was initialized by user input, so they can decide how many search pages to scan through